# socket connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have written code for socket from :[source](http://socket.io/docs/)

My code looks like this.

```
var port = 8081;
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
app.listen(port);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("New user connected.");
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
console.log("server listening on: " + port);
```

But when I am testing it on [here](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html) (ws://localhost:8081). I am getting 
ERROR: undefined 
DISCONNECTED

In console I am getting error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8081/?encoding=text' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the socket.io client library, either getting it, from [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client), or referencing their CDN from your page like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.7.js"></script>
```

Additionally, whenever you start a socket.io server, socket.io will be served from `http://<your-server-address>/socket.io/socket.io.js`. You should be able to test your server using this simple page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="http://localhost:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io('http://localhost:8081/');
            socket.on('news', function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can read more about why you can't connect from the websocket.org site on this [github issue](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/533).

Comment: I have one more question, I got two  implementation  one with require('socket.io') and another with require('ws'). Can you please suggest which one should I choose.  I am developing it for android app.

Comment: In the absence of more info, i'd go with socket.io. It has a number of features like handling the clients reconnection to the server and fallback to other connection types if websockets are not available. I've seen (rather old) benchmarks that show ws being more performant handling more connections, but i don't think the difference is relevant in most cases. Since you're targeting android, you can use their [android native client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) or the regular client if working with webviews.